# If custom field has value, show in slidehow. Else hide

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and the [PODS](http://www.pods.io) plugin and created the pod `project`. In project i've created a set of fields. One of those is `project_slide`. If this field has a value, I want to show this in a RoyalSlider on my frontpage.

I've started with this piece of code (= one slide).

```
<?php
    $project = pods('project', array('limit' => -1));
    while ($project->fetch()) {

        echo '<div class="rsContent">';
        echo    '<img class="rsImg" src="' . $project->display('project_slide') . '" alt="' . $project->display('project_title') . '">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

The problem is: each project I add, displays in the slider. Even if `project_slide` has no value. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I wonder, you've added if-statement to your tagslist, but don't use it in your example, why not? A simple google search for `php check if variable is empty` is very easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just add an if-statement to the loop.
**Hide Image example**
In my example, I only add the slide when the value isn't [empty string]

```
while ($project->fetch()) {
    if( $project->display('project_slide') !== ""){
        echo '<div class="rsContent">';
        echo    '<img class="rsImg" src="' . $project->display('project_slide') . '" alt="' .$project->display('project_title') . '">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

**Expand with a detection if the image actually exists**
You could expand it with a `file_exists` to also check if it exists (for the items with value, but the image itself doesnt exists). Just make sure the file_exists is 2nd, that way it only checks if the file is present if the string is not empty (if-statements go from left to right)

```
$project->display('project_slide') !== "" && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$project->display('project_slide')`
```

---

**Default image method:**
Instead of showing it only when there is an image, you could always show it, but build a default-image logic:

```
$defaultImage = '/some/image.jpg'; // set a default image outside of the loop
while ($project->fetch()) {
    $src= $project->display('project_slide') !== "" ? $project->display('project_slide') : $defaultImage; // set a default umage
    echo '<div class="rsContent">';
    echo    '<img class="rsImg" src="' . $src . '" alt="' .$project->display('project_title') . '">';
    echo '</div>';
}
```